# Choose tests cases to run from Fitnesse test suite

Tags: fitnesse

We have a complex Fitnesse suite with tens of subsuites, includes and symbolic links. Sometimes we don't want to run the whole thing and would like **to run selected test cases and not run the others.** We see two ways to do it:

1. By managing page properties (Suite - Test - Normal), we can turn on/off test cases.

   But this is inconvenient. First of all, it's boring. And second, we can't see the suite current state (what test cases are turned on and gonna be run).
2. In Fitnesse, there are [tags](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuites.TagsAndFilters), and we can specify desired tags in suiteFilter or excludeSuiteFilter.

   This is inconvenient too. You have to remember tag names and don't forget or misspell them in filters. Of course, we can store predefined links with carefully selected lists of tags, but in our case it's not the option, since the lists are subject to frequent changes.

Also, we don't want to divide our suite on several parts, since we benefit from having the general Scenario Library and variable lists.

The ideal solution for us would be having a Fitnesse suite configurator, which could display and change settings of Fitnesse pages. Say, it may be a Fitnesse plugin, which read Fitnesse folder structure and display current settings in an html page or with Windows Form, letting change these settings and save the changes. Or an external tool with similar functionality.

Have you heard of such tools? Did you bump into the same troubles? What would be your suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not know of any plugin which will do what you ask. However, you could use the tags option by adding a top level page to the wiki that you can choose to run tests from.

One final idea would be to use something like [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/) to run each suite. Not really a permanent solution, but perhaps enough to keep you going until one comes up.